# Would Installing a second layer of 1 1/4” EPS foam board help cool a hot garage when placed over the factory installed over factory polyurethane panel

Tags: insulation

I have a small Garage Door Insulation Installation company in Arizona. Many homeowners here have West facing garage door's that can get close to 200 degrees in the late afternoon.
Most homes here have the Wayne-Dalton
9000 Series (economy) factory insulated garage doors with a 10 R-Value (at 75 degrees).
My thermal control idea is to place a second layer of 4.8 R-Value Foil Backed EPS Foam board over that factory polyurethane layer.
What will my end result be to the overall temperature inside that garage space on a hot day (90+)?
Thank you…

Comment: What color is the garage door?

Comment: they vary from light beige to dark brown. The darker the exterior color of the door, the higher the heat transfer temp is.

Comment: How do you feel about "white"?

Comment: White (a non-color) will help attracting and transferring less heat into that garage space.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many variable factors it the actual result may be incalculable.

However common sense says there would be an improvement in heat reduction.

To know the actual result the simplest test may be to take a temp. reading without the extra insulation and another with the extra insul. on the same door.

Comment: Yes…that is what I am finding. People with Mini-Splits, garage attic insulation say they can tell a difference. They say the garage space stays cooler longer, coolest down quicker and that the garage is quieter from outside noise. The homeowners without all that, say the temp difference is negligible after I install.